FastAPI multipart doesn't work with Pycharm
I am creating an App in FastAPI. I am trying to add Oauth for my endpoints. The problem is that everything is fine when I run from the terminal. But when I run from the Pycharm run button, I get this error:
Form data requires "python-multipart" to be installed.
You can install "python-multipart" with:
pip install python-multipart

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hossein/Desktop/CCC_itnoG/fastAPI/fastApiProject_mongo/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    async def token_generate(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
  File "/home/hossein/Desktop/CCC_itnoG/fastAPI/fastApiProject/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 956, in decorator
    self.add_api_route(
  File "/home/hossein/Desktop/CCC_itnoG/fastAPI/fastApiProject/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 895, in add_api_route
    route = route_class(
  File "/home/hossein/Desktop/CCC_itnoG/fastAPI/fastApiProject/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 531, in __init__
    self.body_field = get_body_field(dependant=self.dependant, name=self.unique_id)
  File "/home/hossein/Desktop/CCC_itnoG/fastAPI/fastApiProject/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 815, in get_body_field
    check_file_field(final_field)
  File "/home/hossein/Desktop/CCC_itnoG/fastAPI/fastApiProject/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 100, in check_file_field
    raise RuntimeError(multipart_not_installed_error) from None
RuntimeError: Form data requires "python-multipart" to be installed. 
You can install "python-multipart" with: 

pip install python-multipart

Even though I use the exact same conda environment as the PyCharm environment, it still gives an error. I have installed the python-multipart package in my Conda environment.
Even when I created an entirely new Venv and passed it as a PyCharm interpreter, I was still not able to solve the issue.
This happened only after I decided to use OAuth2, and it seems that it is not avoidable.
I need Pycharm features for debugging.
It seems it is a common problem.
Thanks.

So what happens if you do pip install python-multipart in the terminal inside pycharm - i.e. in your pycharm venv?

@MatsLindh still gives the same error.
